# jQuery UI- How to prevent autocomplete menu from temporarily disappearing between keystrokes?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI autocomplete with data from a remote datasource.  My use case is really similar to the example here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

The only difference is that I set my delay to 0.  In between the keystrokes, the menu disappears for about 1/10th of a second ~100milli seconds prior to the updated autocomplete list being displayed.

Is there anyway I can prevent the menu from temporarily disappearing between keystrokes?  A good use case is google's search, where between keystrokes, the suggestion box does not temporarily disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, it is not a good practice to set a delay of zero when using a remote datasource. It will send more requests than needed and surcharge the server with no benefit.

Anyway, I think you can achieve what you want by defining the `source` option as a callback yourself.

**First a bit of explanaton**. I suppose you are using the remote feature passing an url as the source for the plugin. The plugin actually wraps this into a callback implemented this way:

```
// in case the option "source" is a string
url = this.options.source;
this.source = function(request, response) {
    if (self.xhr) {
        self.xhr.abort();
    }
    self.xhr = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: request,
        dataType: "json",
        autocompleteRequest: ++requestIndex,
        success: function(data, status) {
            if (this.autocompleteRequest === requestIndex) {
                response(data);
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            if (this.autocompleteRequest === requestIndex) {
                response([]);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

As you can see, if there is already an ajax request going on, it abords it. This happenning in your case as a request, as fast as your server can be, takes *some time* and your delay is zero.

```
if (self.xhr) {
    self.xhr.abort();
}
```

This will actually execute the error callback of the aborted request that will execute itself the `response` callback with an empty dataset. If you look at the response callback, it closes the menu if data is empty:

```
_response: function(content) {
    if (!this.options.disabled && content && content.length) {
        ...
    } else {
        this.close();
    }
```

**You can actually define your own `source` callback** to make your ajax request yourself and change the default behavior by not aborting any pending request. Something like:

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: request,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data, status) {
                // display menu with received dataset
                response(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                // close the menu on error by executing the response
                // callback with an empty dataset
                response([]);
            }
        });
    }
});
```